# Twitter bootstrap responsive design doesn't work when accessing via local webserver

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a responisve webdesign which is based on twitter's bootstrap. When I access this page on an webserver which resides in my local network, the responsive features don't work in Internet Explorer on my windows phone 8. Fontsizes are are too big, the fluid columns don't wrap correctly and so on. When I access exactly the same page on a webserver in the internet, everything looks fine.

I also tested this bootstrap example page:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html
Exactly the same result... works when accessing on the web, but not when using the webserver in my network.

Afterwards I tried using another webserver (anuglar's node.js webserver instead of apache)... exactly the same result.

At last I installed the "UC Browser" on my windows phone whose rendering engine is based on webkit... and responsive features still don't work.

Conclusion: There seems to be no issue regarding my sourcecode, the webserver or my browser. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problem description. I mean what do you specifically mean with "too big font sizes", "fluid columns don't wrap correctly" and "so on"?

Comment: It's hard to describe so I took two screenshots of the example page for comparison: http://www.krani.net/misc/twitter-responsive-design.png

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful! I can definitely see its broken.

Comment: Can you paste the HTML you use to include Bootstrap's CSS and JS files?

Comment: Is your meta `viewport` tag added on your local server?

Comment: Thanks for your answers

This is the code i use to include bootstrap:


`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`
`<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`

As you can see the viewport metatag is already there.

Comment: @krani is your issue fixed? I'm also having the same problem.